# Unhandled rejection event have conflict with bugsnag

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, bugsnag

I have some code with many unhandled rejections, and it is very hard to handle all of them. I want to handle them globally with 'unhandledrejection' event.
But I have bugsnag in my project, and when some of the promise rejected, bugsnag catch them first and the app is killed after that. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. It was because my bugsnag version was deprecated and it didn't support an unhandled rejection.
I switch it to "@bugsnag/js": "^6.4.0", and all work very good!!!